# Estrutura de "Estar de acordo"?

Tags: gramática, expressões

Gostaria de saber que estrutura tem "Estar de acordo"?
Se não me engano isso significa "concordar". Agora "de acordo" é um adjetivo ou "estar de acordo" é um expressão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se trata de uma *expressão adjetiva* (ou *locução adjetiva*), ou seja, um conjunto preposicionado de palavras com função de adjetivo.

Assim, "estamos de acordo" é equivalente a "concordamos" e, em alguns contextos, "estamos combinados/acordados".

É mesma construção de "estar de férias", "estar de mal", "estar de cama", etc., assim como também "dos meus pais" é uma locução adjetiva em "casa dos meus pais".